# MYSQL - получить одинаковые значения из n запросов

Tags: mysql

Есть N таблиц, N запросов:

`SELECT id FROM table_a WHERE value = '123',
SELECT id FROM table_b WHERE value = '456',
SELECT id FROM table_c WHERE value = '789',
SELECT id FROM table_d WHERE value = '101112', ...`

Необходимо получить одним запросом только те id, которые есть во всех результатах запросов

Если точнее - если сделать union этих запросов НО получить только повторяющиеся во всех запросах ID

Answer (score 1):

Обычный [`[INNER] JOIN`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)) при объединении выборок из таблиц делает именно то, что вам требуется, в результаты попадают только те записи, которые по условиям объединения присутствуют во всех таблицах. Запрос может выглядеть так:

```
SELECT table_a.id
  FROM table_a
  JOIN table_b ON table_b.id=table_a.id
  JOIN table_c ON table_c.id=table_a.id
  ...
 WHERE table_a.value = '123' and table_b.value='456' and table_c.value='789'
```

Или, в краткой форме (помня, что оператор "запятая" с заданными условиями объединения в MySQL эквивалентен `[INNER] JOIN`:

```
SELECT table_a.id
  FROM table_a, table_b, table_c, ...
 WHERE table_b.id=table_a.id and table_c.id=table_a.id
   and table_a.value = '123' and table_b.value='456' and table_c.value='789'
```