# Запрос MySQL из нескольких таблиц связанных между собой другими таблицами

Tags: mysql

Есть 5 таблиц (так разбито из-за размера. Таблицы имеют units~15k, params~12k, units_params~60k записей):

```
units (id,name)

colors (id,name)
units_colors (unit_id,color_id)

params (id,name)
units_params (unit_id,param_id)
```

Каким образом оптимальнее производить поиск:

```
в названии юнита есть фраза: 'car' 
есть цвет: 'black' и 'green'
нет цвета: 'red'
eсть параметр: 'wood'
```

На данный момент производится поиск сначала по имени. Список подходящих id скидывается в массив. После производится второй поиск по цвету в диапазоне id из массива. и т.д. 
Можно ли выполнить эту операцию одним MySQL запросом?

Comment: одним запросом можно сделать все что угодно. И да это как раз надо делать единым запросом и никак иначе. По слову join любые вопросы ответы тут посмотрите или в гугле вбейте, например http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/618237/

Comment: Ну а "нет цвета" думаю проще всего было бы делать с помощью "`NOT EXISTS`"

Comment: Здесь связь сложнее... Units<->Units_colors<->Colors, а не просто Units<->Colors...

Comment: А какая разница ? в условиях объединения просто указываете нужные столбцы из нужных таблиц

Comment: Ok... со связкой Units<->Units_colors<->Colors понятно.... а как объединить таблицы Units_colors и Units_params джойном? Прежде чем посылать в гугл... прочитайте внимательнее вопрос.

Comment: У меня почти созрел правильный ответ на мой вопрос... Там вам всё станет ясно надеюсь... Ваш ответ совершенно не то что надо... но он меня навёл на правильную мысль...

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from colors 
where id in (
   select units_colors.colors_id from units_colors, units
   where units_colors.unit_id= units.id and
   units.name like 'ваше значение'       
);
```

и т.д.

Comment: Ага... и syntax error.

Comment: Спасибо... Взял за основу... )

Answer (score 0):

Точно по вашим условиям я бы написал как то так:

```
select *
  from units u
 where u.name like '%car%'
   and (2, 0)=(select sum(c.name in('black','green')), sum(c.name in('red'))
                 from units_colors uc, colors c
                where c.id=uc.color_id and uc.unit_id=u.id)
   and exists(select 1
                from units_params up, params p
               where up.param_id=p.id and p.name='wood' and up.unit_id=u.id)
```

Теоретически, если нужно какое то универсальное решение можно было бы остановиться на проверке всех условий тем способом как в этом запросе проверяются цвета и только подставлять параметры в суммы "должны быть" и "не должны быть" и меняя ожидаемые количества совпавших параметров в левой части равенства.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Сложноват для меня, но постараюсь разобрать что здесь к чему.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем за ответы. Пришел к такой цепочке благодаря Ксении. До этого что я пытался делать, были проблемы с логикой запроса. Вариант Майка я пока не разобрал, он немного сложноват для меня.

```
SELECT * FROM units 
WHERE name LIKE '%car%' AND id IN (
    SELECT unit_id 
    FROM units_params, params
    WHERE params.id=param_id AND params.name LIKE '%wood%'
) AND id IN (
    SELECT unit_id 
    FROM units_colors, colors
    WHERE colors.id=color_id AND colors.name = 'black'   
) AND id IN (
    SELECT unit_id 
    FROM units_colors, colors
    WHERE colors.id=color_id AND colors.name = 'green'      
) AND id NOT IN (
    SELECT unit_id 
    FROM units_colors, colors
    WHERE colors.id=color_id AND colors.name != 'red'     
)
```